# Netlogo moving in a circle and stopping half way in the circle

Tags: netlogo

not sure I have tried several ways to make the people move in a circle but they just don't go.  Please help.

Here is my netlogo design, basically i have people standing in a circle but when I ask them to move, i do not know how to ask them to move in the circle.

When I hit the go button in netlogo, they do not even move.  If I use fd 1, they just go everywhere, if i try to use the circle and distance they only go completely around the circle but never stop.

Thanks a Bunch,

R

Answer (score 2):

See the circling example in the NetLogo Models Library:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/TurtlesCircling